# Flutter Provider - ChangeNotifierProxyProvider setting dependencies

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem & dilemmas in setting dependencies with Provider packages.
My code:

```
providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthModel>(          
            builder: (context) => AuthModel(userRepository: UserRepository())),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<AuthModel, AppModel>(
          initialBuilder: (_) => AppModel(),
          builder: (_, auth, app) => app..authModel = auth,
        ),
    ],
```

Using `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider`, changes on authModel makes builder on `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider` to run every time. AuthModel is a ChangeNotifier setting it once as dependency would be enough.

The questions:

1. On every code rebuild(providers is set on build method) does the

   ```
   ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthModel>(          
           builder: (context) => AuthModel(userRepository: UserRepository()))
   ```

recreates the AuthModel instance?

2. On every change on AuthModel the

   ```
   ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<AuthModel, AppModel>(
             initialBuilder: (_) => AppModel(),
             builder: (_, auth, app) => app..authModel = auth,
           ),
   ```

builder assigns again? AuthModel is an ChangeNotifier, doesnt make sense of reassign.

3. On every rebuild, `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider` builder runs again?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The default constructor of `ChangeNotiferProvider` will call `builder` *once and only once*.

`ChangeNotiferProxyProvider`, on the other hand, will call `builder` again every time one of its dependencies updates.

But it is completely fine. Having `builder` being called again doesn't mean that dependents *have* to update. The update is performed only if the `builder` calls `notifyListeners` on the notifier.

Which means your notifier can filter updates like so:

```dart
class MyNotifier with Notifier {
  A _a;
  A get a => _a;
  set a(A value) {
    // don't unnecessarily call `notifyListeners` if nothing changed
    if (value != _a) {
      _a = value;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so to my understanding ProxyProvider will also update once the dependency updates? (dependency extending ChangeNotifier). And one more silly (kind)question: Some operations are recommended to run from initState(), no so much from build. From as I see using Provider, initState cannot be used, build and didChangeDependencies being the VIP.

Comment: Yes, `ProxyProvider` will update too if a dependency changes. The dependency doesn't have to be a `ChangeNotifier` either. All providers have an update mecanism, even `Provider` with `Provider.value`

Comment: You can use `initState` with `Provider.of(context, listen: false)`. But prefer `didChangeDependencies`

Comment: got it :) - `listen
        ? context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(type) as InheritedProvider<T>
        : context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(type)?.widget
            as InheritedProvider<T>;`